# Building dependant projects using jenkinsm maven3 and docker

Tags: java, jenkins, maven-3

How do I import a newly build jar file into a jenkins/Docker automatic build process run using maven3?

I have projectA and the CoreProject (this has all the common methods).
Both are currently set up to build within Jenknin(on docker) using maven, Core is building successfully and creating a Jar file and saving it within it's own project.  Project A is complaining that it does not have access to the core methods.  How can I then import the Core jar into projectA using Maven3/Jenkins?  Or should I be using something else to make this new Jar available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.  I had the Core project building I just was not adding the reference in the projectA pom.xml file.  After following several misdirections i was able to get the ProjectA to build by adding Core Jar following standard maven dependency tags